# play framework upgrade from 2.1.1 to 2.1.3 error

Tags: playframework-2.0

i'm trying to upgrade to 2.1.3 from 2.1.1 ,i tried to follow the [migration guide](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/Migration)  in order to do that.

i download build and export the  path of 2.1.3 framework,

in the plugins sbt file i changed to

```
 addSbtPlugin("play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.1.3")
```

in   the sbt plugin is

```
sbt.version=0.12.3
```

and when im using compile command im getting this error

```
   [NOT FOUND  ] org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.6.6!slf4j-api.jar
```

so i have two major errors  while attempting to upgrade

what im i doing wrong in the upgrade process ??

thanks 
miki

Answer (score 0):

the problem was a mismatch between the 2.1.1   and 2.1.3 so i remove the 2.1.1 folders 
and install 2.1.3 by following this link
[how-to-install-play-framework-2-in-ubunt](http://lazycoderz.com/how-to-install-play-framework-2-in-ubuntu/)

now its all running smooth